# apsrev4-1 error: ! File ended while scanning use of \@secondoftwo

Tags: latex, bibtex, bibliography

I try to use apsrev4-1.bst as bibliographystyle to manage format of my prl (physical review letters) paper. However, I got a error I don't understand. Actually, my code works well if using prl.bst, but report error: "! File ended while scanning use of \@secondoftwo." (the reason I want to use apsrev4-1.bst instead of prl.bst is because prl.bst will show title in reference which I don't know why either). I haven't played with latex for very long time, and this is the first time I deal with bibtex of PRL paper. Can somebody give me a hint how can I solve this problem?

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\documentclass[aps,prl,showpacs, superscriptaddress, lengthcheck]{revtex4-1}
%\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{latexsym}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{apsrev4-1}



\begin{document}


\bibliography{KZ_PRL_v8}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

For me this error was caused by some incompatible items in my bib file.
For example, there was an item in my bib file whose journal was "Computers \& Fluids". After I deleted the "\&", this error message never came out again.
So check the items in your bib file.